# overlay image for "hairline" effect in email

Tags: html, css, image, email, overlay

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I would like a pixel thick white square to overlay an image. 
[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmmgj.jpg)

On a webpage this is easy, I have several options (see below). The issue is that none of them are widely compatible with email:

I have a gif of a white square on a transparent background that I can place on top of the image.

[image]

I can use absolute positioning with z-index to place it on top of the image.

```html
<div style='position:relative;'>
<img src=http://i.imgur.com/fBP9Pxn.jpg style='width:585px;height:440px;position:absolute;z-index:10;'>
<img src=http://i.imgur.com/Hb9jGED.gif style='width:585px;height:440px;position:absolute;z-index:20;'>
</div>
```

I could also set the main image as the background image of a div or table cell, and place the overlay image inside of the div or cell.

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<td style='background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/fBP9Pxn.jpg);background-size:100% 100%;'>
<img src=http://i.imgur.com/Hb9jGED.gif />
</td>
</table>
```

Instead of the overlay, I could have a div with a background image, and inside of that div place another div with a transparent background and white border, and have padding on the parent div to enforce the inset:

```html
<div style='background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/fBP9Pxn.jpg);background-size:100% 100%;height:440px;width:585px;display:block;padding:15px;'>
<div style='display:block;width:585px;height:440px;border:1px solid white'></div>
</div>
```

All of these work fine. The issue is that I am dealing with email.

Email:

Absolute positioning is not consistantly supported. Many email clients will ignore it and just place the first image directly below the second image.

Background images are more widely supported, however `background-size` is largely ignored by email clients. My image can have varying sizes, and it ends up getting cropped which is unacceptable.

I can accomplish what I want by generating an image of the proper size to fit in the email, and then use the `background-image` options. That is what I am currently doing, with the template provided here: https://litmus.com/community/learning/25-understanding-background-images-in-email

The code is a bit uglier because it uses `VML` (Microsoft's version of `svg`) as a fallback, which is required to make the effect work in Outlook 2007/10/13/16 (Interestingly enough, 03 seems to work fine)

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td background="http://i.imgur.com/0JUOCnf.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="585" valign="top">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:585px;">
                  <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/0JUOCnf.jpg" color="#7bceeb" />
                  <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                <div>
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Hb9jGED.gif" alt="Exterior" width="585" style="width:585px;" />
                </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I could even generate an image that has the overlaid square on it. But it is a lot of overhead to generate the image for each email, as well as storage space to store the generated images, since there is a web tool used by people to generate these emails on the fly.

**So, is there anyway to accomplish what I want (without generating custom images for each email) in a way that is widely compatible with email?**

Answer (score 0):

A year and a half later, I've found that: 

**NO**,  there is no reliable way to do this across email clients. For this purpose we just render custom images for each email. It's kind of annoying but the overhead is reasonable and we get good results.